# Using Nested add_action()

Tags: actions

I am new in WordPress.I am learning Plugin Development. Is it possible to use Nested `add_action()` like below ?

```
add_action( 'admin_post_addAddress', 'add_new_address' );

function add_new_address(){
    if($_POST['name'] == '') {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_acf_notice' );
    }

    function my_acf_notice() {
       //Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can call `add_action()` in `add_action()`. Same goes with `add_filter()`. Just make sure that your callback is registered before WordPress runs the hook.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. How to do it `your callback is registered before WordPress runs the hook` ?

Comment: For example, if you want to hook to [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/), make sure you do it (e.g. `add_action( 'init', 'your_function' )`) before WordPress runs `do_action( 'init' )`. But you'd need to check the WordPress *source* to see which hooks run first - or you can try installing the Query Monitor plugin or [see this](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/developer-tools/debug-bar-and-add-ons/#debug-bar-actions-and-filters-addon).

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I have code `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_acf_notice' );` in `admin-post.php`. But the hook `do_action( 'admin_notices' );` is in `admin-header.php`. How can I use `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_acf_notice' );` ?

Comment: What `add_new_address()` does? Why not put the `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_acf_notice' )` and the `function my_acf_notice` to the top level, same level as `function add_new_address`?

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. Now I am using like this `add_action( 'admin_post_addAddress', 'add_new_address' );

function my_acf_notice() {
 //Some code
}

function add_new_address(){
 if($_POST['name'] == '') {
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_acf_notice' );
 }
}`. But it is not working.  Actually I am trying to display a notice for a Form validation in WordPress Admin Panel.

Comment: Why are you not using the [settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/)? I mean, if you are, then the form would be submitted to `options.php` and you would not need the `admin_post_addAddress` hook. So check the settings API and consider using the `sanitize_callback` [option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) to set the callback which you can use to validate the form data/submission - but if you have further questions about the settings API, please post another question (if an existing answer doesn't help you).